# SignTool internal error with cert by SimplySign App from Certum(0x80090020)

Tags: internals, signtool

I get a Ev Code sign in Cloud from Certum. And with the SimplySign app, I do not need to get the USB disk.
  But when sign with the cert, An error occurs:

SignTool.exe sign  /ac "Certum Trusted Network CA.crt" /sha1 afdd9e4c718b41fb7981ee32c55837035bdb9abe /t http://time.certum.pl /fd sha256  /v dmfs.sys
The following certificate was selected:
    Issued to: Beijing Healthy Hailstone Technology Co., Ltd.
    Issued by: Certum Extended Validation Code Signing CA SHA2
    Expires:   Sat Dec 12 19:28:35 2020
    SHA1 hash: AFDD9E4C718B41FB7981EE32C55837035BDB9ABE

Cross certificate chain (using machine store):
    Issued to: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Expires:   Sat Nov 01 21:54:03 2025
    SHA1 hash: 8FBE4D070EF8AB1BCCAF2A9D5CCAE7282A2C66B3

```
    Issued to: Certum Trusted Network CA
    Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Expires:   Fri Apr 16 04:25:34 2021
    SHA1 hash: 55435515FDD2486575FDC5CF3BAD00C913123D03

        Issued to: Certum Extended Validation Code Signing CA SHA2
        Issued by: Certum Trusted Network CA
        Expires:   Tue Jan 19 19:55:39 2027
        SHA1 hash: BC432D6E675FF26B7BA71C24EA469A7D5457C745

            Issued to: Beijing Healthy Hailstone Technology Co., Ltd.
            Issued by: Certum Extended Validation Code Signing CA SHA2
            Expires:   Sat Dec 12 19:28:35 2020
            SHA1 hash: AFDD9E4C718B41FB7981EE32C55837035BDB9ABE
```

Done Adding Additional Store
SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2146893792/0x80090020)

Under the condition, I do not know how to process the error. And Why it occurs.
Is any idea?

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue?